# ZSH Completions based on a directory

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I have a function set up in ZSH to quickly navigate to a folder within my ~/Sites directory.

```
site() { cd ~/Sites/"$1"/website/; }
```

So if I type `site clientsite` it will cd into ~/Sites/**clientsite**/website/, nothing too complex going on here.

I am wondering how I get this to autocomplete based on the folders that I have inside `~/Sites/`.

So when I type `site cli[HIT TAB]` it will autocomplete to `site clientsite`.

Comment: The alias seems unrelated to your actual question.

Comment: Ah right your are. I have removed it from the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the two lines you have:

```
alias sites='cd ~/Sites'
site() { cd ~/Sites/"$1"/website/; }
```

Add these two lines:

```
_site() { _files -W ~/Sites; }
compdef _site site
```

That should give you the tab completion you're looking for.

Comment: Brilliant! That is exactly what I was after!